# Drawable folder not found in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When ever I drag an image to drawable folder it shows an error message path not found iam using visual studio 2019.
So I used URL but it is unreliable as some images fail to load when there are several images in the app.
Iam creating a view cell with images I have created the drawable folder and added it in code but it is not working

Comment: Please provide more details / screenshots. You have a drawable folder, in Android soltuion, and you can't add images?

Comment: Please check your project's architecture, the drawable folder may not exist there. You can manually create it in VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it manually. It will have mipmap folders instead. But you can add drawable folder manually and it will work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it seems like you are manually dragging it to the folder, and so it is not getting "included" into your project through Yourproject.Droid.csproj file.

Follow theses steps Inside your Visual Studio:

1. right click on the drawable folder,
2. select "Add Files",
3. then find your file and "Open" it, and
4. in the following window, (shown below) select "Copy the file to the directory and press OK[image: VS Window that pops up]

And now your error should go away

Comment: I use windows version of visual studio right click on drawable folder add existing file select the file click  it is showing path not found I can only add as link

Comment: Check to see if in the folder of your solution, the droid project has the drawable folder. If it does, then check to see if the csproj file includes the drawable folder from the right place. Also, the other option you have since it is allowing you to add as link, just add the resource to a resources folder of your core project through visual studio. Then add that resource as a link in your droid project !

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclude drawable folder from project

   [image: 1. Exclude drawable folder from project]
2. Add drawable folder as existing folder

   [image: 2. Add drawable folder as existing folder]